# return a float array from java to jni

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

I'm calling a java method from jni.This method return a float[]

```
   jclass javaClass = env->GetObjectClass(activityObj);
   jmethodID method = env->GetMethodID(javaClass,"findparam", "([FF)F");
   jfloatArray rotateArray = env->CallFloatMethod(activityObj, method, s1, s2);
```

But when i tried to compile it i had :

```
   error: cannot convert 'jfloat' to '_jfloatArray*' in initialization
```

how can i get the returnet float array??

Comment: i think i found it :Use CallObjectMethod. For example:

jmethodID myMethod = (*env)->GetMethodID(myClass, "myMethod", "()[I");
jintArray retval = (jintArray) (*env)->CallObjectMethod(myObject, myMethod);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try to use `jfloatArray  imageArray = (jfloatArray) env->CallObjectMethod(Object,method);`

It should resolve your problem .

Answer (score 0):

All array types (even primitive types) are returned as a `jobject` which you should then cast to the appropriate `j<type>Array` type.

So your final line should read:

```
jfloatArray rotateArray = (jfloatArray)env->CallObjectMethod(activityObj, method, s1, s2);
```

Answer (score 0):

`CallFloatMethod()` is for calling methods that return `float`. You are calling a method that returns `float[]`. You should be calling `CallObjectMethod()`.